# correlationid for azure events

Tags: node.js, azure-eventhub

What is the correct way to add a correlation-id to azure events ?

Right now, I send the events as follows:

```
const { EventHubProducerClient } = require('@azure/event-hubs');

const producer = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName);
const batch = await producer.createBatch();
batch.tryAdd({
  body: {
    foo: "bar"
  }
});
await producer.sendBatch(batch);
```

Of course as a workaround I could just add my own field to the body. However, I suspect that there is a built-in mechanism or default approach to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release exposes a [correlationId](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/@azure/event-hubs/eventdata?view=azure-node-latest#correlationId) property on `EventData`, which corresponds to the `correlation-id` field of the [message properties](http://docs.oasis-open.org/amqp/core/v1.0/os/amqp-core-messaging-v1.0-os.html#type-properties) section of the underlying AMQP message.

One important call-out is that the `correlationId` is intended to enable tracing of data within an application, such as an event's path from producer to consumer.  It has no meaning to the Event Hubs service or within a distributed tracing/AppInsights/OpenTelemetry context.